# DataGridView Invalid Casting Exception

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting

I'm trying to calculate percentages based on one cell's value to another cells value.  The data looks like this, only larger, but the idea is the same:

```
     c1    c2    c3   tot

r1    1     0     3     4

r2    1     2     1     4  

r3    0     0     1     1

tot   2     2     5
```

All the values in any cell are only ever integers.  I'm trying to create a table that looks like this:

```
     c1    c2    c3

r1    0.25  0     0.75

r2    0.25  0.50  0.25

r3    0     0     1
```

I don't need help creating the table--I can actually create the table--I just can't get the casting correct in order to populate the table with the correct (percentage) data.  I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 7; i < 12; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
  {
    double hold1 = (double)gridHolder.Rows[i - 7].Cells[j + 1].Value;
    double hold2 = (double)gridHolder.Rows[i - 7].Cells[8].Value;
    gridHolder.Rows[i].Cells[j + 1].Value = hold1 / hold2;
  }
}
```

`gridHolder` is the name of the table, in case that wasn't obvious.

When I run it, I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PCHG Simulator.exe

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

How do I convert the contents of the cell into a `decimal` or `double` so that the division will be a decimal result?  If you could also explain how to format the result into 2 decimal places, that would be great, but I'm sure I can figure that out otherwise.

**EDIT:** I don't know if it's worth noting, but, if I cast as `int` for each:

```
int hold1 = (int)gridHolder.Rows[i - 7].Cells[j + 1].Value;
int hold2 = (int)gridHolder.Rows[i - 7].Cells[8].Value;
```

it works just fine, except for the obvious problem that the division becomes integer division and not decimal division.  So the problem is clearly with the way that I am attempting to cast to a double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Convert.ToDouble(value)

Comment: Haha wow.  I was hoping it would be that simple of a change!  Thank you!! :D